# ON DUPLICATE KEY concatenates *every* value of column

Tags: mysql, string, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

This is a head-scratcher.

I am using `CONCAT` in the context of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and it is spitting out very strange results.

Assume that a table exists with two columns and three rows, thus:

```
term   | reference
0cm    | 49-5;
10p    | 890-1;
11s    | 491-1;
16761  | 768-1;
```

(Despite the numbers, these are all VARCHAR strings.)

Now assume that we run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dictionary (`term`,`references`) 
VALUES 
('0cm','35-6;'),
('10p','89-12;'),
('16761','491-7;') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`references` = CONCAT(`references`,'35-6;'),
`references` = CONCAT(`references`,'89-12;'),
`references` = CONCAT(`references`,'491-7;');
```

Because `term` is a unique index, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` becomes the active portion of the script (save for the unaffected `11s`). The expected behaviour is that our new values will be *appended* to the existing values.

The query runs successfully, but gives me these unexpected results:

```
term   | reference
0cm    | 49-5;35-6;89-12;491-7;
10p    | 890-1;35-6;89-12;491-7;
11s    | 491-1;
16761  | 768-1;35-6;89-12;491-7;
```

It has concatenated *every* value of `reference`.

Is there some way to "clear" the `reference` reference before `ON DUPLICATE KEY` performs its `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VALUES(references)` to get the value that was going to be inserted into that row if it didn't have a duplicate key.

```
INSERT INTO dictionary (`term`,`references`) 
VALUES 
('0cm','35-6;'),
('10p','89-12;'),
('16761','491-7;') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`references` = CONCAT(`references`,VALUES(`references`));
```

BTW, you should read this: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Barmar plus Bill Karwin giving me obvious hints? I am listening! I'll give that a good read. But for the exercise and hopefully the edification of the community, I will see this through first. I will add my update here. Thanks.

Comment: Bingo. That did it. I did not know the correct way to reference the `VALUEs` currently in the `reference` field. Thank you for this lesson. Btw, "reference" must be a restricted term, and would not work unless it was back-ticked in each case: ``references``. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, `references` is used when declaring foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dictionary (`term`,`references`) 
VALUES 
('0cm','35-6;'),
('10p','89-12;'),
('16761','491-7;') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`references` = CASE term WHEN '0cm'   THEN CONCAT(`references`,'35-6;')
                         WHEN '10p'   THEN CONCAT(`references`,'89-12;')
                         WHEN '16761' THEN CONCAT(`references`,'491-7;')
                         END;
```

or simply

```
INSERT INTO dictionary (`term`,`references`) 
VALUES 
('0cm','35-6;'),
('10p','89-12;'),
('16761','491-7;') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`references` = CONCAT(`references`, VALUES(references));
```

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Removed.

Comment: Good answer, Akina, Thank you.  But Barmar's is just so much cleaner. Keep in mind this may be 1,000s of rows added in one go. Still, the WHEN/THEN is a good strategy.

Comment: @Parapluie CASE technique is more general - sometimes the value assigned in ODKU may be non-dependent by the value inserted. VALUES() usage is a special case (but, of course, the most frequent). That is why I give both variants.

Comment: Understood. It's nice to have that variant.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
INSERT INTO dictionary (term, references)
VALUES 
('0cm','35-6;'),
('10p','89-12;'),
('16761','491-7;') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    references = CONCAT_WS(';', references, VALUES(reference));
```

This appends to column `reference` when a duplicate `term` is given. Note that `concat_ws()` properly handles the edge case where `références` is initially `null`.